# Positive voltage out of the DAC R-2R

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac

I implemented an R-2R DAC on a breadboard. Obviously, the output voltage from the DAC is negative. I would like to compare in the operational amplifier comparator a positive voltage so I need to transform the output voltage from the DAC. 
How can I do this?
Thank you so much. [image]

Comment: "Obviously the output voltage from the dac is negative" is it? my r2r ladders only work with positive voltages...

Comment: I added an image so you can compare the circuits, thank you

Comment: Throw in another unity gain invertor.

Answer (score 2):

Feed the output of DAC to an inverting amplifier with unity gain.